# PHP: Storing base_64 data in cookies

Tags: php, cookies, base64, mcrypt, setcookie

I need to store some data in a cookie. The data goes through `mcrypt` encryption and then `base64` to prevent any strange characters being used.
Storing the encrypted & encoded string in a session and reading it back & decrypting/decoding works perfectly. Doing the same to a cookie fails - completely gibberish text is returned.

Obviously this is due to the fact that the `mcrypt-decrypt` function call receives improper data, making me to believe that the contents of my cookie are affected in one way or another.

**What on earth is PHP doing behind the scenes to my cookie data?**

Code:
*(Note that the mcrypt-functions are represented below as plain function call for readability  )*

```
$string = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( 'A string' ) );
setcookie('string', $string, time()+3600);
$_SESSION['string'] = $string;

$sessiondata = base64_decode( mcrypt_decrypt($_SESSION['string']); // A string!
$cookiedata = base64_decode( mcrypt_decrypt($_COOKIE['string']) ); // Completely gibberish
```

Comment: maybe related to applied character encoding!?

Comment: Wouldn't the session contents also be affected then?

Comment: Before trying to decode the string, see what's in `$_COOKIE['string']` first and make sure it's the same as `$_SESSION['string']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling urlencode() on your string before sending it to the cookie -- I seem to recall that PHP automatically does a urldecode() on the data when making it available in $_COOKIE.